# How to change login to work on get instead of post spring security

Tags: spring, http, get

I have following spring security configuration, How do i change to it login to work based on http GET instead of POST, so that login url will be something like:

`*http://localhost/myapp/j_security_check?j_username=test&j_password=test*`

This is my configuration xml file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http  access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/pages/accessdenied.jsp" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> 

         <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="GET"/>
         <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <form-login
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
            default-target-url="/landing"
            login-page="/login" />

        <logout
                 invalidate-session="true"
                 logout-success-url="/login?logout" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" /> -->

    </http>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" ></beans:property>    
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager" >
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>'
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Why? In general you don't want to pass the username and password as request parameters as that isn't really secure...

Comment: Client want to log in to application using both get and post methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring 3.0 Security http GET login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814346/spring-3-0-security-http-get-login)

Comment: But There in no answer

Comment: IMHO you should convince your client to not want to login using GET as that has serious security implications, parameters are there for everyone to see. Using GET for logins with username/password is inherently unsafe. But if you really must you need to do manual configuration of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and set the property `postOnly` to `false`.

Comment: Can you provide code how to implements UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Answer (score 0):

For more information, If you want to send your form with method post through spring security. You need to add this token to your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```